# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at String.replace (<anonymous>) when calling async function in server component

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

My **page.tsx** is doing data fetching to query the database and input to a client component:

```js
import CsvDownloader from "./csv-link";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import db from "./dbSchema";

export async function getData() {
  await mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://<acccount>:<passowrd>@xyz.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
      dbName: "exmapledbName",
    }
  );
  const data = await db.find({});

  return { props: { data } };
}

export default async function Page() {
  const data = await getData();
  return (
    <div>
      <CsvDownloader data={data} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

My **csv-link.tsx** looks like:

```js
"use client";

import { CSVLink } from "react-csv";

export default function CsvDownloader({data}) {

  return <CSVLink data={data}>Download me</CSVLink>;
}
```

When I run the code, the error occurr:

```
⚠ Fast Refresh had to perform a full reload due to a runtime error.
 ✓ Compiled in 91ms (666 modules)
 ⨯ RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
 ⨯ RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
digest: "353717507"
```

Why maximum call stack size exceeded? I only call the async function once without any loop. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please share link to GitHub repo or any other environment where this can be reproduced.

Comment: I think what is happening is that you are fetching to much data at once for it to be fetched from by mongoose or be passed to the client component.